# Find this if $\mbox{cosec}( x) =$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $csc(x) = 9$

without a calculator evaluate:

i) $\cot(x)$

ii) $\tan(x)$

iii) $\cos(x)$

I know that $\csc(x) = \sin(x)$ divided by $1$. But I don't know what $x$ is. Not sure what to do to find $x$.

I know $\cot(x) = \tan(x)$ divided by $1$.

$\tan(x)$ is just the tan of $x$ (still need to find $x$ lol).

Lastly, I know that $\cos x$ is $\cos x$.

Comment: I think you mean that $\csc x$ is $1$ divided by $\cos x$ and not the other way around. $\cos x$ divided by $1$ is $\frac{\cos x}{1} \equiv \cos x$. Also: are you sure that you have given all of the details? These questions usually say that $x$ is acute, obtuse or reflex.

Comment: Ah thank you for that correction. If cosec(x) = 9 would that mean sin(x) = 1/9?

Comment: Also the question says "showing your working and leaving your answers in the surd form", but doesn't give us what the angle is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\csc(x)=9=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{adjacent}}$$

We don't need to know the exact length, but from this we know the ratios. We know that the sides of the hypotenuse and the adjacent can be, respectively, $9$ and $1$, $18$ and $2$, etc. Hence, we know that the third side can be $\sqrt{80}$, $\sqrt{320}=2\sqrt{80}$, etc. But basically, it won't matter because the $2$ or whatever the coefficient is will cancel and we will remain with the sides having the ratio of $\sqrt{80}:1:9$ (where $\sqrt{80}=4\sqrt{5}$ is the opposite, $1$ is the adjacent, and $9$ is, of course, the hypotenuse). This is all we care about for trig *ratios*.

With this, you should be able to answer everything.

i) $\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}$

ii) $\tan(x)=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{1}=4\sqrt{5}$

iii) $\cos(x)=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac{1}{9}$

Cheers!
-Shahar

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, Shahar!

Comment: @user136213 No problem. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you draw a right triangle with hypotenuse 9 and vertical leg 1. Then $x$ is the angle opposite the 1.

(Check that $\csc x = 9$ for this triangle.)

Can you then find the length of the horizontal leg using Pythagorean theorem?

With all three legs known, computing the requested trigonometric ratios will be easy based on their definitions.

Comment: A right-angled triangle is not enough. Let $\sin x = \frac{3}{5}$. We have $\cos x = \frac{4}{5}$ if $x$ is acute and $\cos x = -\frac{4}{5}$ if $x$ obtuse.

Comment: Fair enough, I was assuming less than 90 degrees based on context clues.